# Proving $6n-1$, $6n+1$, $6n+2$, $6n+3$, $6n+5$ to be relatively prime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be an integer. Prove that the integers $6n-1$, $6n+1$, $6n+2$, $6n+3$, and $6n+5$ are pairwise relatively prime.

I tried to prove that the first two integers in the list are relatively prime.

$$(6n-1-(6n+1)=1$$
$$6n-1-6n-1=1$$
$$-2=1,$$
which is obviously not true.

Not sure where to go from here. Is there another way to prove that two integers are relatively prime?

Comment: HINT: $1\leq\gcd(a,b)\leq|a-b|$.

Comment: You can't assume $(6n-1)-(6n+1)=1$ even if you know they're relatively prime. All that $(6n-1)-(6n+1) = 2$ tells you is they're both odd, hence relatively prime wrt 2; but you already knew that from their construction.

Comment: Hint: 5 numbers, residues modulo 6. Pigeonhole Principle

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Suppose a prime $p$ divides two of these numbers. Then $p$ also divides their difference, which is one of the numbers $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, $6$. It follows that $p=2$ or $p=3$. Can you finish from there?

Also see [Show that among every consecutive 5 integers one is coprime to the others](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1745136/).

Answer (score 0):

Say the claim is false.

Say a prime $p$ divides any two of them. So $p$ divides their differences.But the possible differences is $1,2,3,4,6$. As $p$ divides one in this set,$p$ must be 2 or 3. But no 'two numbers' in the original set are even. Hence 2 is not possible.

And Only $6n+3$ is divisible by 3. Hence 3 can't divide two of them.

So our assumption is false. So, they're pairwise relatively prime.